# After insert id in textbox click enter fill data in html table using ajax php sql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I need to fill all matching records in a table after inserting id in textbox. But currently I am getting only one record.

php

```
<?php
 $id=$_POST['userID'];
 $db_host = 'jo\SQL2005';
 $db_username = 'jo';
 $db_password = '123321';
 $db_name = 'db_test2';
 mssql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password);
 mssql_select_db($db_name); 
 $query=mssql_query("select * from address where user_id='$id'");
 $result=mssql_fetch_assoc($query);
$json= array('id'=>$result['id'],'user_id'=>$result['user_id'],
'street'=>$result['street'],
'quarter'=>$result['quarter'],'Phone_number'=>$result['Phone_number']);
 echo json_encode($json);
 exit;

?>
```

javaScript

```
function getname()
{
var id=$("#userID").val();    // get the id from textbox
$.ajax({
        type:"post",
        dataType:"json",
        data:"userID="+id,
        url:"address_json_data.php",   
        success:function(json)
        { 
          $("table.imagetable").
           append("<tr><td>" + json.user_id + "</td><td>" +
            json.street + "</td></tr>");
        }
        });
       }
```

html

```
<input name="userID" id="userID"  onChange="getname()" type="text" />
<table border='1'class="imagetable">
<tr><th>id</th><th>email</th></tr>
</table>
```

Any Help Very Thanks

Comment: add header("Content-Type: text/json"); before echo json_encode($json);

Comment: mike O i am try but not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this code:

```
$query=mssql_query("select * from address where user_id='$id'");
$result=mssql_fetch_assoc($query);
$json= array('id'=>$result['id'],'user_id'=>$result['user_id'],
'street'=>$result['street'],
'quarter'=>$result['quarter'],'Phone_number'=>$result['Phone_number']);
```

with this:

```
$query=mssql_query("select * from address where user_id='$id'");
while($result=mssql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
   $json[]= array(
                  'id'=>$result['id'],
                  'user_id'=>$result['user_id'],
                  'street'=>$result['street'],
                  'quarter'=>$result['quarter'],
                  'Phone_number'=>$result['Phone_number']
  );
}
```

And in your javascript:

```
success:function(json)
    { 
      var str = '';
      for(var x in json)
      {
         str += "<tr>";
         str += "<td>" + json[x].user_id + "</td>";
         str += "<td>" +json[x].street + "</td></tr>";
      }
      $("table.imagetable").append(str);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mike O work 99% but if insert other id in textbox need to empty past data table how this

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more explanation?

Comment: ok, one try insert id 2 then get all records for 2 second try insert id 3 in my case get id 2 and 3 but i need second try just id 3

Comment: can you paste your insert code here? that might help

Comment: the same code (insert) not insert db but insert number in textbox to get resualt

Comment: In that case, instead of: $("table.imagetable").append(str); try this: $("table.imagetable").html(str); Let me know if it works